# 3DES_CMAC encryption using online tools or OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, smartcard

I have a smart card that claims that its mutual authentication is based on 3DES_CMAC algorithm.

In the first step, the user sends a random number to the card and the card calculate the encrypted value of that challenge and returns it to the user.  below you can see a test case :

User challenge (Random value) : `8E AC 1A AA 96 BB 59 02`

Calculated value (Card respond) : `D0 CB 74 A9 C5 80 39 55`

My authentication keys are : `404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f`

I want to check if the card do its job well or not! But I didn't find any tool to do a 3DES_CMAC. Neither online tool nor OpenSSL tool .

How I can check it?